# How Linux system knows what files/subdirectories are under one directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode, vfs

I'm reading the book "Linux Kernel Development", and there are some important points:

1. inode doesn't include filename.
2. filenames are stored in directory entry(dentry).
3. but dentry is not stored on disk, it's dynamic generated.

> Unlike the previous two objects, the dentry object does not correspond
> to any sort of on-disk data structure.TheVFS creates it on-the-fly
> from a string representation of a path name. Because the dentry object is
> not physically stored on the disk, no flag in struct dentry specifies
> whether the object is modified (that is, whether it is dirty and needs
> to be written back to disk).

So the question is: where exactly the file names store? and how "list directory" works?

Comment: @EsaJokinen thanks for your link. I checked through the answers and seems no one answered where did dentry get the filename. since dentry is dynamic generated, there must be a place to store such information. correct me if I'm wrong. thanks.

Comment: Why would it need to be stored if it is dynamically generated?

Comment: I think I found the answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398434/why-no-file-name-in-inode-information